# Converting data from TFDQuery to String in Embarcadero C++Builder

Tags: c++, mysql, c++builder, firedac

**How to convert data gotten from a FireDAC query (MySQL database) to a String**? I have the code shown below:

```
String query_id_person = "select max(id_person) from data"; //query to database
FDQuery1->SQL->Text = query_id_person; //assigning value of query to Query component
FDQuery1->Active = true; //"Running" Query
```

How to get the result data from this query to the String in C++?

```
String ID_PERSON = FDQuery1->???(value?)
```

Comment: I can't test this myself, but instead of setting `FDQuery->Active = true; `, try [`FDQuery1->Open();`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDRdbmsDataSet.Open), then [`FetchAll()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.FetchAll) and you may find what you need in [`Data`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.Data) (but I'm not sure how to copy the value out of `Data`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FieldByName function to read the contents of individual fields in the dataset:

```
const String FieldNameYouWantToRead = "Your field name here";
String ID_PERSON = FDQuery1->FieldByName(FieldNameYouWantToRead)->AsString`;
```

Comment: You can also access fields by index instead, eg: `FDQuery1->Fields->Fields[0]->AsString`